# Term for someone who has an eye for detail

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, expressions

Is there a term that could describe this sort of person? Like, an eye for detail in arts, an eye for detail as to what is the cause of a conflict (something which other people hadn't seen yet), an eye for detail, which is why a photo was taken from the right angle or perspective.

Answer (score 3):

You mention two different use cases.

> an eye for detail in arts ... an eye for detail, which is why a photo was taken from the right angle or perspective

Like [jimsug](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24232/6407) and [ChristopherW](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24230/term-for-someone-who-has-an-eye-for-detail#comment45748_24230), my immediate inclinations are *meticulous* and *keen-* or *sharp-eyed*. I don't know of a single adjective (or even a concise phrase) which has this meaning and also carries a specifically artistic connotation. I can only recommend general terms and suggest that you add modifiers to specify the artistic bent. Other potential choices:

- [Assiduous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/assiduous)
- [Sedulous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sedulous)
- [Scrupulous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scrupulous) (very often used in a moral or ethical sense)
- [Fastidious](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fastidious) (very often used when speaking about cleanliness)
- Detail-oriented

> an eye for detail as to what is the cause of a conflict (something which other people hadn't seen yet)

For this case, I'd use *astute*. [1](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/astute), [2](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/astute). It applies specifically to situational assessment, and I would not use it to describe an artist's attention to detail, e.g. when painting or composing a photograph.

Answer (score 2):

You could call them:

- [meticulous](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/meticulous), though this *might* have a negative connotation, depending on the context - as has been pointed out, not always:

  > very precise about details, even trivial ones; painstaking
- [vigilant](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vigilant), though this has a bit of a supervisory/oversight connotation to it:

  > keenly alert to or heedful of trouble or danger, as while others are sleeping or unsuspicious

And.. both of those entries have synonyms and links to thesaurus entries:

> thorough, detailed, particular, strict, exact, precise, microscopic, fussy, painstaking, perfectionist, scrupulous, fastidious, punctilious, nit-picky
>
> watchful, alert, on the lookout, careful, cautious, attentive, circumspect, wide awake, on the alert, on your toes, wakeful, on your guard, on the watch, on the qui vive, Argus-eyed, keeping your eyes peeled or skinned

I'm intuiting that what you want is closer to *meticulous* than *painstaking*, though.

Comment: I was looking for a positive term, mainly. Like, some people's brains might just enable them to have more eye for detail. Some of the terms you mentioned are a bit negative, perhaps? Like, fussy, painstaking and nit-picky e.g.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd describe "meticulous" as having a negative connotation. To describe someone as being *negatively* detail-orientated, I'd probably use words like *pedantic*, *nit-picker* or *fussy*

Comment: @Matt true, this would depend on the co-text/context.

Answer (score 2):

I usually refer to people like this as *observant*.

> Ted noticed that Kathy and Carol are no longer friend despite always being cordial.
>
> Yea, he's a pretty *observant* person.

Observant is not typically used with tangible objects though. While it can be, I believe [jimsug's first word is a better fit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24230/term-for-someone-who-has-an-eye-for-detail/24232#24232).

Another word that comes to mind is *thorough*. Thorough simply means that all the details have been examined. You would want a *thorough* airplane mechanic running quality control to ensure planes are ready for takeoff. You would want an *observant* manager to realize that a mechanic is *thorough* enough for the job of quality control.

Answer (score 0):

The another lesser known term for it is "anal". 
This [wikipeida link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anal_retentiveness) must be able to help you

Answer (score -1):

I’d go with [perceiver](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perceiver) or [percipient](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/percipient) that are defined as:

> A person who becomes aware (of things or events) through the senses.
>
> One that perceives.

Comment: -1 because those sound extremely unidiomatic to me. An English speaker would be much more likely to use the adjective *perceptive* than *percipient*.

Comment: @ Matt, thank you, I fairly appreciate that you explained your reasons. If anyone did like you we, learners, would really be helped and the site would function better.

Comment: @LucianSava But if you changed your answer to say *perceptive*, I could upvote it :-)

Comment: @Snailplane, sorry but I'm afraid I can’t do that. Perceptive was my first reaction but I couldn’t find to be defined as a noun, all dictionaries define it only as adjective, and I think OP asks for a noun.

Comment: @LucianSava Oh!  I'm sorry, I thought *percipient* was (only) an adjective, so I didn't realize you were trying for nouns specifically.  I see now that dictionaries say it's a noun, too!  (I don't see any indication that the question is asking for a noun, but I s'pose someone could ask the OP and find out!)

Comment: @Snailplane, I think you’re right and I misread the question. My bad.